# Sharing a windows directory in win 8?

Tags: vb.net, windows-8

I succeed to share folder in WinXP and Win7 ([Using this method](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/de213b61-dc7e-4f33-acdb-893aa96837fa/c-set-directory-sharing-permission-full-control-for-everyone-programmatically-in-windows-7-or?forum=windowssdk))
But I have a problem, when I'm trying to share a folder using Win8.
It gives me an error and says that I have to run an .exe file as administrator.

Comment: Yes you will need to be an administrator to do this. The same I suspect is true on Windows 7 if UAC is turned on.

Comment: I turn UAC off on Win 8 and I still can't share dir..
I think that I must run program as administrator programaticaly, but I don't know how to do it since my program is on .net 2.0.?

Answer (score 0):

If your original program is not running Elevated and you want to start an application elevated (As Admin) you will have to do something like this (this will prompt for elevation):

```
 Dim procStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
    Dim procExecuting As New Process

    With procStartInfo
        .UseShellExecute = True
        .FileName = "FileName.exe"
        .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
        .Verb = "runas" 'add this to prompt for elevation
    End With

    procExecuting = Process.Start(procStartInfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you application manifest so that it will only run as an administrator.

`Application Properties>Application Tab>View Windows Settings`

Then change this line to `requireAdministrator`

`<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`

See this for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tzdks800(v=vs.120).aspx

Also see this SO question on the same topic: [How do I force my .NET application to run as administrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7)

Comment: I can't find "View Windows Settings" under App Tab in V.S. 2005?

Comment: I think this setting came in in Visual Studio 2008 it was then called `View UAC Setings` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tzdks800(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Ok, but how I can do that in V.S. 2005?